# When is it required to define a separate function in Python

Tags: python, function

In my code, I am printing a menu

```
print(num_chars * char)

for option in options: 
    print("{:d}. {:s}".format(option, options[option]))

print(num_chars * char)
```

The code `print(num_chars * char)` prints a separator/delimiter in order to "beautify" the output. I have learned from several coding tutorials that I am not allowed to write the same code more than once.

Is it really preferable to define a function

```
def get_char_repeated(char='*', num_chars=30):
    """
    Return the character repeated an arbitrary number of times
    """
    return num_chars * char
```

and call this two times in my original code?

Are there any alternatives if I need to print nice looking menu from a dictionary?

Thank you.

Comment: **Never.** You can write all of your logic in one huge script without any functions or classes. **But that is a very bad idea.**

Comment: If the print function is doing what you want, why define another function? I agree that you should always strive not to repeat yourself, but writing a custom function for this doesn't seem to help with that.

Comment: [Same question on Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/269882/is-it-always-a-best-practice-to-write-a-function-for-anything-that-needs-to-repe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have learned from several coding tutorials that I am not allowed to write the same code more than once.

This principle, called "don't repeat yourself" (DRY) is a good rough guideline. For every programmer who writes too many functions (splitting code into too small units), there are 20 who write too few.

Don't go overboard with it, though. The reasoning behind DRY is to make reading and changing the code later on easier. `print(num_chars * char)` is pretty basic already, and super-easy to understand and change, so it doesn't really pay off to factor it into a function.

If the repeated code grows to 3 lines, you can (and probably should) factor it out then.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary at that level. What might be helpful is if you were often doing that whole block of code, you could easily change it to

```
def printOptions(options, char='*', num_chars=30):
    print(num_chars * char)

    for option in options: 
        print("{:d}. {:s}".format(option, options[option]))

    print(num_chars * char)
```

The main point of functions is to save time with blocks of code you use a lot in a very similar way by not retyping/copy pasting them. But they also save time when you make changes. If you used the same function in 10 different places you still only need to change it once for all 10 uses to be updated rather than having to find all 10 manually and update them.

So if you decided you wanted to put a title header into this menu printing section and you had used it as this or a similar function in a bunch of places, you could quite easily update them all without difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

I find it a good rule, that if the code you're turning into a function is used more than once and takes up more than 3 lines, it is a candidate to be turned into a function.  If it is a very complex single line of code (like this `x = [ i**j for i in z for j in y ]`) and is used more than twice, it could be a candidate to turn into a function.

It may be a matter of preference where you draw the line but the basic idea is if it makes your code easier to read or easier to write, turning something into a function can be a good idea.  If it makes your code harder to read (because every time you see the function you have to look back at the specifics of what it does), you probably should not have turned that code into a function.